# How to copy xml file from res/Values folder programmatically to sdcard in android

Tags: android

I want to copy string.xml file as it is to the sdcard. But I am not able get any method to do so. I want to do something like this.

Code:

File f = some method to load string.xml file say like new File("file path") or getResource M ethod().

and then code for copy to sdcard.

I am not able to create a file object of string.xml.

Please help me on the same.

Thanks in Advance....

Ketan Bhangale

Comment: please post more codes. plus, what is the destination path you want to copy to ?

Answer (score 0):

Those xml files are compiled and you can't read in as input stream directly. However, You can load all the strings and write them to a file.

```
Field[] allStrings = R.string.class.getFields();
    for(int i = 0; i < allStrings.length; i++) {
        try {
            String str = getResources().getString(allStrings[i].getInt(null));
            // write it to file or Do what you need to do.
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```